# Duplicate id generate

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-cosmosdb, guid

I am creating a project using **asp.net core web api** and cosmos db. I generate the id as GUID value, I auto generate the id.But it create duplicate value.

work.cs file:

```
 public class work
        {
            [JsonProperty("id")]
            public Guid Id { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("name")]
            public string name { get; set; }

            public List<Industy> Industy { get; set; }
            public work()
            {
                if (Id == null)
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                }
                else
                {
                    Id = Id;
                }
            }
        }
```

Industry.cs file:

```
public class Industy
    {    
        [JsonProperty("Id")]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("IdustryId")]
        public int IdustryId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("IdustryName")]
        public string IdustryName { get; set; }


        public Industy()
        {
            if (Id == null)
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            }
            else
            {
                Id = Id;
            }
        }    
    }
```

**output:**

```
>  {
>     "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
>     "Name": "string",
>     "industy": {
>       "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
>       "IdustryId": 0,
                 }
>  }
```

If i enter more than one value without id it show me the error ,id is already exist. please help me to fix it.

Comment: Compiler should give you a warning that comparing to null will never be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mexanich has good solution. Still you can try one more approach. If you don’t want to change your property to `nullable` then Update condition like below. Also there is no need for `else`  block. You can eliminate it.

```
if (Id == default(Guid))
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Mark `public Guid Id { get; set; }` as nullable in both models:

`public Guid? Id { get; set; }`

Guid is a struct and value type. This means you have to compare with its default value instead of null or mark it as nullable.